# Mercadopago android sdk payment method by cardnumber

Tags: android, kotlin, payment, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

i'm stuck in getting the payment method of a cardnumber with the Mercadopago android sdk. I'm using a custom form and creating a CardToken, but for complete my request i need the payment method ("visa", "master", ...)

I read the documentation but i couldn't find how to get it

I think there's a method getPaymentMethodByBin, but i can't find it

I'm using the version com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.1

I'm also using the [braintree payment form](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Please provide your problem (is it error, or any unexpected result, what are you expecting), your stack traces, your codes that directly involved.

Comment: Is no exception, the thing is that I don't see any method which I could use to get the payment method